# Android: Returning to a specific Fragment after Activity finishes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a FragmentActivity and I am currently using a fragments ability to hide and show, via the fragment support manager. That way I have faster fragment switching since I will need all pages loaded anyways.

I then call another activity and after I'm done with it use its .finish() method to stop it. I want my view to return to the fragment I was previously on. However it is always opening in the very first fragment ever created/shown.

Example:

```
Fragments[] frags = new Fragments[SIZE]
fragOne.show();
fragTwo.hide();
```

Button is clicked:

```
fragOne.hide();
fragTwo.show();
```

Then another action is performed to star the new activity:

```
new Intent();
startActivity(//Code to start activity);
```

Activity is finished:

```
this.finish();
```

In my previous activity I attempt to show the previous fragment"

```
onResume(){
  showFragment(CACHED_FRAGMENT);
}
```

HOWEVER, even after debugging and noticing the cached_fragment is indeed my second fragment, only the first one will show.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little confused as to what you are trying to accomplish here, however the following code might help you.

In your Activity, load the first Fragment if savedInstanceState is null in your Activity's onCreate() method. This will ensure that the first Fragment is not created again on orientation change.

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentOne());
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); 

}
```

The above method will load your first Fragment into the content frame you have in your Activity's layout.

When you want to show your second Fragment use the following method

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentTwo());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The above method will replace your first Fragment with your second Fragment and add the second Fragment to the back stack. Adding the second Fragment to the back stack ensures that the back button will navigate from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne instead of closing the app in your first Activity.

When you call your second Activity via Intent, do not call finish() on the first Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the help John. However I switched from using .replace() to .hide and .show. I'll post a better question later this week but have been very busy recently.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write your fragment loading code in the activity a's OnResume:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        .replace(R.id.mainFragID, FragOrdersHolder())
         .commit()
    }
```